# How to use JAXB to marshall/unmarshall a collection of MyBean

Tags: java, collections, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a MyBean annotated

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyBean ...
```

Marshalling/Unmarshalling MyBean w/o problems, e.g.

```
JAXBContext jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyBean.class);
Marshaller m = jaxbCtx.createMarshaller();
m.marshal(myBean, writer);
```

How can I use JAXB to marshall/unmarshall a Collection or List?

My attempt results in this error:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.util.ArrayList" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:230)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create another element of type `MyBeanList` and use it. Something related on SO [Using JAXB to unmarshal/marshal a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603404/using-jaxb-to-unmarshal-marshal-a-liststring)