# How can I unmarshall a collection of root elements with JAXB?

Tags: xml, serialization, collections, jaxb

From some library, I'm getting such an input string:

```
<link>
    <name>button1</name>
    <target>there</target>
</link>
<link>
    <name>button2</name>
    <target>there2</target>
</link>
```

(note that this is not an XML document as it has no root) and I have this class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "link")
public class TableTagLinkElement {
    private String name;
    private String target;

    // getters and setters
}
```

How can I unmarshall this easily into a list of `TableTagLinkElement`s, **in a generic way such that I could implement such a method:**

```
public <T> List<T> parseCollection(String xmlString, Class<T> rootClass)
```

i.e., without any previous knowledge of the `TableTagLinkElement` class or of the name of the `<link>` tag?

I know about solutions that [create a wrapper class with a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315466/how-to-use-jaxb-to-marshall-unmarshall-a-collection-of-mybean), but I think they're not applicable here, are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wrap a `<root>...</root>` element around the complete XML string, then you could create an `XMLStreamReader` reading from that string, then loop over the reader, unmarshalling each `link` as you go.  For example (exception handling omitted)

```
public <T> List<T> parseCollection(String xmlString, Class<T> rootClass) {
  XMLInputFactory inFac = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
  XMLStreamReader reader = inFac.createXMLStreamReader(
                    new StringReader("<root>" + xmlString + "</root>"));
  reader.nextTag(); // move to the <root> tag
  reader.nextTag(); // move to the first child
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
  while(reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
    list.add(declaredType.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader)));

    // unmarshal leaves the reader pointing at the event *after* the
    // closing tag, not the END_ELEMENT event itself, so we can't just
    // do nextTag unconditionally.  We may already be on the next opening
    // tag or the closing </root> but we might need to advance if there
    // is whitespace between tags
    if(reader.getEventType() != XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT &&
       reader.getEventType() != XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT) {
      reader.nextTag();
    }
  }
  reader.close();
  return list;
}
```