# JAXB: How to marshal objects in lists?

Tags: xml, jaxb, arraylist, unmarshalling

Perhaps a stupid question: I have a `List` of type `<Data>` which I want to marshal into a XML file. This is my class `Database` containing an `ArrayList`...

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Database
{
    List<Data> records = new ArrayList<Data>();

    public List<Data> getRecords()                   { return records; }
    public void       setRecords(List<Data> records) { this.records = records; }
}
```

...and this is class Data:

```java
// @XmlRootElement
public class Data 
{
    String name;
    String address;

    public String getName()            { return name;      }
    public void   setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getAddress()               { return address;         }
    public void   setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }
}
```

Using the following test class...

```java
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Data data1 = new Data();
             data1.setName("Peter");
             data1.setAddress("Cologne");

        Data data2 = new Data();
             data2.setName("Mary");
             data2.setAddress("Hamburg");

        Database database = new Database();
                 database.getRecords().add(data1);
                 database.getRecords().add(data2);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Database.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                   marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                   marshaller.marshal(database, new FileWriter("test.xml"));       
    }
}
```

...I got the result:

```xml
<database>
    <records>
        <address>Cologne</address>
        <name>Peter</name>
    </records>
    <records>
        <address>Hamburg</address>
        <name>Mary</name>
    </records>
</database>
```

But that's not what I was expecting, i.e. all tags for `<Data>` objects are missing. I am looking for a way to export the data in the following structure, but I don't know how to achieve this:

```xml
<database>
    <records>
        <data>
            <address>Cologne</address>
            <name>Peter</name>
        </data>
        <data>
            <address>Hamburg</address>
            <name>Mary</name>
        </data>
    </records>
</database>
```

---

One additional question: if I want to deal with the problem **without** using `@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement` annotations, I can introduce an intermediary class

```java
public class Records
{
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();

    public List<Data> getData()                { return data; }
    public void       setData(List<Data> data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

used by the modified base class

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Database
{
    Records records = new Records();

    public Records getRecords()                { return records; }
    public void    setRecords(Records records) { this.records = records; }
}
```

in a slightly modified `Test` class:

```java
...
Database database = new Database();
database.getRecords().getData().add(data1);
database.getRecords().getData().add(data2);
...
```

The result also is:

```xml
<database>
    <records>
        <data>
            <address>Cologne</address>
            <name>Peter</name>
        </data>
        <data>
            <address>Hamburg</address>
            <name>Mary</name>
        </data>
    </records>
</database>
```

Is this the **recommended** way to create a Java class structure according to the XML file structure above?

Comment: I don't see you using `DataList` in your test class.

Comment: Pardon me - i copied & pasted the wrong class... It's now corrected in the example above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JAXB to unmarshal/marshal a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603404/using-jaxb-to-unmarshal-marshal-a-liststring)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

On the records property add:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="records")
@XmlElement(name="data")
```

For more information on JAXB and collection properties see:

- [JAXB & Collection Properties](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html)

Comment: @LawrenceTierney - The following article on `@XmlAccessorType` may help with annotating fields or properties (getter/setter):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: @XmlelementWrapper is not applicable to type - compilation error message. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

This is in response to your second question disquised an answer:

- [JAXB: How to marshal objects in lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683598/jaxb-how-to-unmarshall-objects-in-lists/3686065#3686065)

Both approaches will generate the same XML.  My recommendation is go with the model that is best for your application.  For me that is generally using @XmlElementWrapper/@XmlElement.  Since "records" is just there to organize the "data" elements it doesn't really deserve its own class.

I lead the [MOXy JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation and we offer an XPath-based mapping extension to go beyond what is capable with @XmlElementWrapper:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: It's really quite impressive what's going on in this area. I think i need some time to get in touch with this new mapping technique. Can you give me a first hint, how to read exported XML data into the class structure again? If i use @XmlElementWrapper/@XmlElement for the export, the import program complains that the corresponding classes are (obviously :-) not existing...

Comment: The import (unmarshal) should just work, what exception are you getting?

Comment: I think i got an exception that class 'Records' could not be find. But to be sure, i will verify it by an example tomorrow...

Comment: Yes, you are right, unmarshalling works as expected! --- JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Database.class); Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller(); Database database = (Database) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("test.xml"));

Comment: I would have posted this on your blog but it seems like only team members can respond there. Thank you for your sample code, but is there a cleaner way to do this now in 2017 without the boilerplate classes and strict typing?

Answer (score 5):

In response to your second question:

```
Is this the recommended way to create a Java class structure
according to the XML file structure above?
```

Technically speaking, introducing an extra `Records` class to solve your JAXB issue is unnecessary and redundant work, because JAXB does not need it. The 
`@XmlElementWrapper` and `@XmlElement` `name` property have been designed to solve your issue.

From your comments to Blaise's answer, I maintain a [tutorial](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/08/jaxb-annotation-summary-advanced-topics.html) with operational examples explaining how do deal with generic classes such as List, etc.. when unmarshalling.