# How to marshall ArrayList<Object>[] in JAXB?

Tags: java, arrays, jaxb, arraylist

I have a variable (list) of type ArrayList[] and I want to save it in XML. I tried JAXB, but it saves only the "" String (the repetition of " is equal to list.length) and no items in ArrayLists. If I tried the 2d array it works fine. If I tried ArrayList, it works also fine. How can I solve this problem?

My code is similar to:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeClass {

    @XmlElement(name="part")
    private final ArrayList<Object>[] list;

    ... constructor, which fills the list variable

}
```

Can someone tell me how to do this? Please.

Comment: This answer might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1603404/850326

Answer (score 2):

You should not mix generic types with arrays - Look at [Item 25 in Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf). Use 2D array or list of lists.

Comment: I used this type (ArrayList<Object>[]), because the length of the array is constant, so I thought it wasn't necessery to use the ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>, but if is no other way I have to use this list of lists. Can I ask why I should not mix generic types with arrays? I don't see any problem (except JAXB saving) with this mixing...
But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for explain me why I should not mix generic types and arrays.
But if I used ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> (list of lists) it is not still working. So I probably have to use XmlAdapter, but I dont now how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Thank yout for your effort, but I finally found a solution :). I covered one list by another class and it's working fine.:

```
@XmlElement(name="part)
MyClass[] list;

@XmlRootElement
class MyClass {
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    ArrayList<Object> list;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need an array of list objects? If not you could also use two lists:

```
Private LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>> parts;
```

This works well with jaxb.

Comment: Ok, I will use it, I just thought is not necessery to use list of lists :), because the length of the array is final (constant).

Comment: I think if you initialize the array list instead of the linked list, there should be no difference.

Comment: I think so too. But I think it is not necessery to use ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> if I can use ArrayList<Object>[] (the length of the array is constant)

Comment: So, I tried ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>, but it is still not working. Can someone help me how to make it work? I just need a list of lists and save it with JAXB to XML.