# Json: Response issue in apache CXF and ArrayList

Tags: java, json, list, web-services, cxf

I'm a beginner with Apache CXF , and I had created json web-services but i have a problem with in invoking List in my web services

I want a full explanation to my problem and the exact steps to overcome this problem

this the output when i invoke my web services with a ArrayList:

```
No message body writer has been found for class java.util.ArrayList, 
ContentType: application/json
```

Comment: have looked at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311396/no-message-body-writer-has-been-found-for-response-class-arraylist) .Also it would be helpful if you could post the code what you have tried so far.

Comment: @ Rajith Pemabandu this the  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084899/json-response-issue-in-apache-cxf-when-this-response-is-an-list) that contains the code