# Restful service endpoint to produce XML response for ResponseEntity< HashMap<String, Serializable>>

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to implement a RESTful service endpoint which produces XML responses. The return entity for this service call is a HashMap which has the data for the output to be generated. But I keep getting the following exception while invoking the service:

> HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable
>   representation

To investigate the issue, I wrote another endpoint which produces a response for a single object (say, Employee). I have annotated this class with `@XmlRootElement` and invoking it works just fine. If I remove the `@XmlRootElement` annotation from the Employee class, this endpoint will also fail  and give the same exception which I mentioned above.

As per my understanding the root object in the `ResponseEntity` should be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. My problem centers around how to use this annotation on collections like Map, List etc..

All help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible -- you will most likely have to create some sort of wrapper or DTO around your Collection/Map. This: [Using JAXB to unmarshal/marshal a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603404/using-jaxb-to-unmarshal-marshal-a-liststring) I believe is related to your use-case.