# JPA, REST, unmarshalling the list of elements

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I have a GET function in my REST service that returns the list of objects in XML format.

```
@GET
@Path("all")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Customer> findAll() {
    return getJpaController().findCustomerEntities();
}
```

How can I unmarshall the list of XML to the list of objects? 
I would like to store all these customers from database into some List or Vector of Customers objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JAXB to unmarshal/marshal a List<String>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603404/using-jaxb-to-unmarshal-marshal-a-liststring)

Answer (score 1):

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response 
{
   @XmlElement
   private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

   public Response(List<Customer> customers)
   {
      this.customers = customers;
   } 

   public getCustomers()
   {
      return customers;
   }
}
```

unmarshalling

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXB.unmarshal(source, Response.class);
```

where `source` is any input stream (file, stream)

```
@GET
@Path("all")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Response findAll() {
    return new Response(getJpaController().findCustomerEntities());
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, but I don't have idea why always my list is empty.