# Spring MVC to Spring REST tutorials misunderstanding

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, rest

I have developed a Spring MVC - Hibernate application as told [here](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html).

Now I am trying to modify this code to create a REST application as told [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/spring-3-restful-web-services.html).

I have added `Jackson` library to the classpath and added `@XmlRootElement`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "persons")
public class Person implements Serializable {
```

But if I do a `application/json` request then I still get the `html` code back.

**What I am doing wrong / forgot to do?**

My controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getPersons(Model model) {

        logger.info("Received request to show all persons");

        // Retrieve all persons by delegating the call to PersonService
        List<Person> persons = personService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("persons", persons);

        return "personspage";
    }
```

Changed the Controller, but get an error:
t

```
ype Status report

message /Buddies/WEB-INF/jsp/main/persons/1.jsp

description The requested resource (/Buddies/WEB-INF/jsp/main/persons/1.jsp) is not available.
```

Comment: Show us your controller method. Are you returning `Person` object from your method and have `@ResponseBody` annotation over controller method as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Person getPerson(@PathVariable int id) {
    Person person = personService.getPersonById(id);
    return person;
}
```

If you want to return a list of `Person` objects, you need an extra wrapper object, see: [Using JAXB to unmarshal/marshal a List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603404).

Comment: I have added a @pathVariable, but get an error, that type Status report

message /Buddies/WEB-INF/jsp/main/persons/1.jsp

description The requested resource (/Buddies/WEB-INF/jsp/main/persons/1.jsp) is not available.

Comment: @Bob: in `web.xml`, which paths are mapped to `DispatcherServlet`?

Comment: One more question: application/xml request is success and I see all my data, but application/json fails. What can be the problem?

Comment: @Bob: should transparently work for both of them, providing you are sending `application/json` (?) and `jackson.jar` is on the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) and messageConverter in your spring configuration.