# REST API Response

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I am creating restful web services. I need to get the Response of GET method as List of all Categories whose site Id is 1. when I run the following code it will not give the error

```
@GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/bysite/{siteId}")
    public List<Category>getSubCategoryBySite(@PathParam("siteId") String siteId) {
       List<Category> categoryList = categoryFacade.retrieveCategory(Integer.parseInt(siteId));
        ParentCleaner parentCleaner=new ParentCleaner();
        Site site=parentCleaner.getEmptySite();
        for(int i=0;i<categoryList.size();i++)
        {
            site.setSiteId(categoryList.get(i).getSiteId().getSiteId());
            categoryList.get(i).setSiteId(site);            
        }
        return categoryList;
    }
```

but when i run the following code

```
 @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        @Path("/bysite/{siteId}")
        public Response getSubCategoryBySite(@PathParam("siteId") String siteId) {
           List<Category> categoryList = categoryFacade.retrieveCategory(Integer.parseInt(siteId));
            ParentCleaner parentCleaner=new ParentCleaner();
            Site site=parentCleaner.getEmptySite();
            for(int i=0;i<categoryList.size();i++)
            {
                site.setSiteId(categoryList.get(i).getSiteId().getSiteId());
                categoryList.get(i).setSiteId(site);            
            }
            return Response.status(200).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(categoryList).build();
        }
```

it gives the following error

```
SEVERE: A message body writer for Java class java.util.Vector, and Java type class java.util.Vector, and MIME media type application/json was not found
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
  com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyMessageBodyWorker
  com.sun.jersey.moxy.MoxyListMessageBodyWorker

SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.Vector, and Java type class java.util.Vector, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.Vector, and Java type class java.util.Vector, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Please consider making the title more relevant.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603404/using-jaxb-to-unmarshal-marshal-a-liststring