# Java: Can I use JAXB to serialize a list of strings?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

I have nothing more complex than a list of strings.
I have implemented several methods to make simpler use of JAXB to serialize various classes.

The List exists inside no other classes, it's just a simple List that I need to load into a ComboBox at run time, and allow the user to save/load the contents of at their leisure.

Is it possible for me to use JAXB to serialize a List object, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If the list is referenced by a field in a serialized class, you can annotate it with @XmlElement. See also this possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603404/using-jaxb-to-unmarshal-marshal-a-liststring

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but it will be less efficient than a simple wrapper class with a `List` field.

Following your comments on @BlaiseDoughan's answer, here is your `SaveableList` implementation. Basically what you need is a class which implements `List` and forwards all calls to an internal `List` implementation, e.g. `ArrayList`. In my example I extend `AbstractList` for simplicity.

**`SaveableList` implementation:**

```
class SaveableList extends AbstractList<String> {

    @XmlElement(name="e")
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String e) {
        return list.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    // You might want to implement/override other methods which you use
    // And is not provided by AbstractList

}
```

**Example usage:**

```
List<String> list = new SaveableList();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");

// Save it to XML
JAXB.marshal(list, new File("list.xml"));

// Load it from XML:
List<String> list2 = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("list.xml"), SaveableList.class);
```

**Here is the XML it generates:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<saveableList>
    <e>one</e>
    <e>two</e>
</saveableList>
```

Answer (score 0):

JAXB requires the object you are marshalling to be a domain object.  Therefore you would need to introduce a wrapper like the following to do the marshalling.

```java
 @XmlRootElement(name="strings)
 public class ListOfStrings {

     private List<String> strings;

     @XmlElement(name="string")
     public List<String> getStrings() {
         return strings;
     }

     public void setStrings(List<String> strings) {
         this.strings = strings;
     }

 }
```

Comment: That's of what I was afraid. I was really hoping to avoid that... Oh well. Is it possible to implement the List<> class into another class and use that?

Comment: @Will I'm not sure what you mean by `Is it possible to implement the List<> class into another class and use that?`?

Comment: Well, could you do say the following:
@XmlRootElement(name = "SaveableList") public abstract class SaveableList implements List{}